# Правильный селект в Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, php7, laravel5

Есть таблица Offers с полями price и points. 
Предположим есть 10 offers нужно из них посчитать по нарастанию первые 3 у которых наименьшая цена и наибольшее количество очков.
Подскажите как это можно сделать. Спасибо заранее !

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал как-то так.

Модель Offers:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Offers extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'offers';
}
```

OffersController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Offers;

class OffersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
    $offers = Offers::orderBy('price', 'asc')->orderBy('points', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();

    return view('offers', compact('offers'));
    }
}
```